# How does a semisimple Lie algebra determine its root space?

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

I understand that given a root system $\Phi$, by Serre's theorem there exists a Lie algebra $L$ with root system $\Phi$. Also isomorphism theorem implies that any two such $L$ are isomorphic. That means $\Phi$ determines $L$ up to isomorphism.

Now given $L$, we can find two maximal toral subalgebras $H$ and $H'$, therefore two root systems $\Phi$ and $\Phi'$. Humpreys says in his book

> In order to show that $L$ alone determines $\Phi$, it would surely suffice to prove that all maximal toral subalgebras of $L$ are conjugate under Aut $L$.

I want clarification on two things

1) By saying $L$ alone determines $\Phi$, does he mean $\Phi\cong \Phi'$ or stronger $\Phi = \Phi'$, that is, does $L$ determine its root space completely or up to isomorphism?

2) I don't see how is that by showing all $H$ are conjugate under Aut $L$ will imply the result in 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) He means up to isomorphism.

2) If any two $H$ are conjugate by an element of $L$, 
then this conjugation will induces an isomorphism between the corresponding
character lattices, which will further induce an isomorphism between
the corresponding 
roots systems.